# Uploading multiple files with formData and nestJs

Tags: nestjs, form-data, class-validator, class-transformer

I have a nested entity of menu, each menu has a title and a list of categories, each category also has a name, an image, and a list of items, and in the same way each item has a title and an image.

I want to create a single request to upload this, so obviously i need to create a POST request with formData. I have 2 questions about this.

1. How should I handle the the file structure, how can i know which file relates to which category/item, I cant attack files to the from data like this

   formData.append('images', category[0].imageFile)

   etc. for each entity, but that way i lose the connection and I won't know which image goes where, what is the best approach for such a scenario?
2. How can I handle this properly on the nestJs side? Im sending the categories as a stringified json (formData.append('categories[]', JSON.stringify(categories[0])). On the server(nestJs) I have a createMenuDto that looks like this:

example:

```
 export class CreateMenuRequestDto implements ICreateMenuRequest {
        @Expose()
        @Type(() => CreateCategoryRequestDto)
        @IsArray()
        @IsObject({ each: true })
        @ValidateNested({ each: true })
        categories: CreateCategoryRequestDto[];
    
    
        @Expose()
        @IsString()
        title: string;
    }
```

the issue is
when sending the actual request i get a 400 "categories.each value in nested property categories must be either object or array"
this is how the formData that was sent looks like:

```
categories[]: {"title":"cat1","menuItems":[{"title":"item 1","price":null}]}
```

title: test

So my question again is what is the best approach here, i can add a transform to JSON.parse each category back, but is there a different way to send nested entities? or a different way on the nestJs side?